# Cocoapod: how to push spec to my private repo without lint?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, lint

I'm having my own cocoapod which is wrapper to C++ library, so it can't be used without having per-architect shared library. I'd prefer to add `*.a` in the project that is using this cocoapod so cocoapod obviously fails at linking while linting. How can i push podspec to my private repo skipping lint?

Comment: Are you willing to distribute source with the wrapper or just a static lib? Is using a static framework an option?

Comment: just wrapper sources. the project that i using that lib will required to compile lib for specific target and add to the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no answers were done I assume it's impossible or it's not a good practice. So I've created common repo directories structures in repo, copied PodSpec file and committed/pushed it. After that I was able to use it just like it was pushed using `pod repo push ...`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! For anyone interested the correct repo structure is defined in cocoapods docs under "3. Add your Podspec to your repo": https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: I don't understand what your setup is that bypasses the validation. Can you explain a bit more? Do you mean you made your repo very thin — just so that you can pass the validations. Then pushed again to the same version and pushed all the files — including ones that were causing the lint to fail?

Comment: @mfaani A cocoapods repository is really just a git repository that stores podspec files in a defined file structure.  If you clone the pods repository (rather than the repository that has the source code) then you can create a new directory for the new version of your pod, copy in the podspec file and push your changes.  That gives the same result as running `pod repo push`, but without having to lint the podspec.

Answer (score 12):

When I need to do that I perform the following steps:

1. Open the CocoaPods script file with a text editor:

   ❯ atom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.2.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/push.rb
2. Comment the validating line:

[image]

3. Try to publish the pod again.

Don't forget to undo the change. If the project maintainers do not add a flag for this, they have their reasons.

Comment: To find push.rb you can use pod trunk push --verbose. this will log the file location. Comes handy in case of rvm or smth similar.